# How can I pass a state from a function component so i can use it in the use-Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

so am trying to get some data in a form of a state in react.js and i need to use it in the useContext so i can perform an Api call so please if someone can help that would be a please <3 and really helpful and thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do:

```js
// MyComponent.js

import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

// Note that you have to export the context to use it elsewhere
export const MyContext = createContext(null);

const MyComponent = () => {
 const [myState, setMyState] = useState();

 // Provider provides the context to components that are nested under it
 return (
  <MyContext.Provider value={{ myState: myState, setMyState: setMyState }}>
   <MyChildrenComponents />
  </MyContext.Provider>
 );
};
```

`value` is accessible in any component that's nested under the provider. In this case, the provider is `<MyContext.Provider>`. And `value` is accessible in `<MyChildrenComponents />`.

--

To extract `value`, we use `useContext` as such:

```js
// MyChildrenComponents.js

import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './MyComponent.js';

const MyChildrenComponents = () => {
  const { myState, setMyState } = useContext(MyContext);
  
  // ...
}
```

You can read more about React context [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) (the docs).